# HTMLObjectElement onclick event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, html, html-object

I'm using an HTMLObjectElement to display svg graphics as recommended here: https://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/

The problem is that in javaScript I've done something like:

```
const objEl = document.createElement( 'object' );
objEl.type = 'image/svg+xml';
objEl.data = 'myGraphic.svg';
objEl.onclick = () => {
  console.log( 'I was clicked' );
}
```

and the onclick event is never fired when I click on it with my mouse.

If I use an img rather than an object, then the click event does fire.  Why doesn't the click event work for objects?  How can I get click events?

Note, I have also attached objEl.onmouseover and objEl.onmouseout events and they work just fine.  It is only the click events that don't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried using addEventListener()?

Comment: `<object>` element is bound to the same rules as `<iframe>` element, and indeed, it won't let the parent document know what happens inside its contentDocument and won't bubble the pointer events it received. Since you are dispalying an svg document, you could add a script in it like `onclick = e => parent.postMessage({x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY}, '*');`. https://jsfiddle.net/j8y4h28L/

Comment: That's no good.  Say I have 10 svg's and I want to know which svg I am clicking on.  It sounds like I need to update all 10 svg's to have some sort of script inside it to report back to the parent that it was clicked.  The parent would then also have to listen to these messages.... I'm going to see if there is any other way of using svg's that doesn't require me to edit the svg's to be notified when they are clicked.  I have way to many svg's to edit this way.

Comment: @MarekKnows.com You can also try as proposed in the dupe: access all the inner docs from your main doc and attach your click events from there. HTMLObjectElement even offers a `getSVGDocument` method, but this technique is bound to same origin policies.